# Cannot play the video although OpenCV did not give any error when creating the video in Python

Tags: python, opencv, frame-rate

I am trying to create videos consisted different frame rates (5, 10, 20, 30, 40) from a 50 frame video. I want the first and the last frames to be stable (first: 0.00 sec frame, last: 0.98 sec frame). The other ones will be selected randomly from 50 frames of the video.

I found the codes from the internet, so I could not completely understand it. For this reason, the changes that I made do not work.

Actually, the code in below works (at least it does not give any error) but when I try to play the output, I cannot because the video player says that the video is broken. At first, I tried to cut the first 5,10,20,,30,40th frames of the video and it did work. However now I have to put frames randomly between the beginning and the end.

And also I have to insert the frame rates and the video name manually since I could not do it in a loop (I have 6 different videos and 5 different fps rates to cut).

I hope I could explain it clearly and I hope someone can help me because I've been trying the solve this for a looong time. :(

Thanks in advance!!

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import os
import random
from os.path import isfile, join

 # Cutting frames


vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture('/work/rubbing_dooh_50fps.mp4') 
def getFrame(sec): 
    vidcap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC,sec*1000) 
    hasFrames,image = vidcap.read() 
    if hasFrames: 
        cv2.imwrite("framecatch/rubbing_dooh_frame "+str(sec)+" sec.jpg", image)     # save frame as JPG file 
    return hasFrames 
sec = 0
frameRate = 0.02
success = getFrame(sec) 
while success: 
    sec = sec + frameRate 
    sec = round(sec, 2)
    success = getFrame(sec)

# Creating a video from the frames


def convert_frames_to_video(pathIn,pathOut,fps):
    frame_array = []
    

    files = [f for f in os.listdir(pathIn) if isfile(join(pathIn, f))]


    for i in random.sample(range(1,48),3):
        filename=pathIn + files[i]
        #reading each files
        img = cv2.imread(filename)
        beg = pathIn + files[47] #corresponding first frame
        end = pathIn + files[22] #corresponding last frame 
        imgbeg = cv2.imread(beg)
        imgend = cv2.imread(end)
        height, width, layers = imgbeg.shape
        size = [height, width]
        print(filename)
        #inserting the frames into an image array
        frame_array.append(img)
        
    frame_array.append(imgbeg) #probably i shouldn't use append here
    frame_array.append(imgend)

    out = cv2.VideoWriter(pathOut,cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v'), fps, size)

    for i in range(len(frame_array)):
        # writing to a image array
        a = out.write(frame_array[i])
    out.release()
def main():
    pathIn= '/work/framecatch/'
    pathOut = 'rubbing_dooh_5fps.mp4'
    fps = 5.0
    convert_frames_to_video(pathIn, pathOut, fps)

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Are you sure that /work/rubbing_dooh_50fps.mp4 is the correct path and spelled correctly.

Comment: @fmw42 yes, I am sure, and when I use the code without adding end and beginning, it works correctly

Comment: What is filesize?